# Is there a Ghostery equivalent for Firefox on Android?

Tags: security, firefox-for-android

I use Firefox on a smartphone with limited RAM, where [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) would be most useful (removing useless content). Plus I don't like being tracked anyways.

So is there an equivalent to Ghostery that supports the Android version of Firefox?

Comment: Well, there's something which should come in very close according to [this page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/android/addon/ghostery/reviews/). I take it is the Ghostery addon for Firefox on Android. Then there's Ghostery for Opera, according to [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=24686474). But no exact hits to my knowledge, sorry.

Comment: @Izzy : unfortunately firefox says it's not compatible. I tried with both stock firefox and firefox beta.

Comment: I was already afraid so. It looks suspiciously as if simply all available addons are listed in the "Android branch", whether they work on Android or not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ghostery for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/) has been reworked to enable it to work with Firefox for Android. Click the link, install and enjoy not broadcasting everything you do to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Ghostery for Firefox has not been officially released yet, you have to wait a bit until its out.

Comment: Please provide an official source for the software.

Comment: Always provide some sort of proof that you are related to the software. Even better, provide a link to the official homepage of ghostery where an interested user can download the preview version (after accepted the usual disclaimer)

Comment: Sid, Flow, Evidon is owner of Ghostery, therefore my response qualifies as official since I did include my email address there.